# SVCHOST.EXE is taking 90% of RAM

Tags: windows-7, windows

My friend's laptop always get crushed, caused by svchost.exe that take large percent of memory to work. Almost 90% RAM is used while it working. Many friends said that caused by Viruses. How to solve the problem without reinstalling Windows? because so many applications were installed and no backup already made.

Comment: If infection is a suspect, check for weird behavior and unnecessary network activities... You shall be helped in that case by free forums like bleepingcomputer.com and geekstogo.com

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SVCHost is NOT taking up 90% of the RAM.

I recognize that you may have some software saying that it is.  However, I assure you, it is NOT.

SVCHost is basically a fancy (documented) trick that Microsoft uses to have multiple "services" look like a single process.  The real source of the problem is almost never actually SVCHost, but it is one of the processes that gets disguised as SVCHost.  Yeah, this complicates troubleshooting.  However, there are some speed benefits, so combining multiple software into a single "process" does have some legitimate purpose.  (So this is not necessarily indicating a virus.)

Try:
`TASKLIST /SVC`
Then you can match the PID to some services.

Or, try Resource Monitor (Task Manager, Performance tab), CPU.  In the "services" section (which you may need to expand), you can sort by PID to see what services are using it.

I've found that in the business world, common culprits were software that heavily use the disk (e.g., backup software).  I guess that such software often works with drivers that may handle things at a low level, and so such actions may often involve software that is designed for speed rather than user-interactivity (like showing a proper "process" name).

All this said, viruses can also cause problems like high CPU usage, and have been known to hide as SVCHost.exe.  So, you might be dealing with a virus.  However, you also might not be.  In my experience troubleshooting many computers (for multiple businesses that were professionally managed), malicious software was the less common case.  Thorough troubleshooting generally found a fixable cause other than viral activity.

Answer (score 3):

This memory usage may be caused by Windows Update which scans for new updates. Microsoft released an Updates which lower the memory usage.

**Windows Update Client for Windows 7: June 2015** 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3050265

> **Fixes included in this update**
>
> This update addresses an issue in which system performance can be decreased during scans. This issue has the greatest effect on
>   computers that have a small amount of physical memory.

Download and install the update.

32Bit: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=47352
64Bit: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=47351

Answer (score 2):

Try using svchost viewer. https://svchostviewer.codeplex.com/

And from another website (can't remember where):

Applications Are Accessing The Internet From Your Windows Computer

There are plenty of third party tools that help you in achieving this. A popular example of such tool can be CurrPorts by Nirsoft, which is a portable application, displaying all open connections and listening ports.

But what if you want to check this natively without using any third-party option? To do this, you can either use Windows PowerShell or the very popular and easy to use Command Prompt. The following steps will help you detect applications that are using your Internet bandwidth with Command Prompt. This is one of the simplest and easiest way to keep track of your connections.

Step 1: Hit the Windows key on your keyboard, and search for cmd.exe by typing it in.

Step 2: You need to run cmd.exe as an administrator. To do that, Right-click on it, and select ‘Run as administrator’.

Step 3: Type the following command and hit enter:

```
netstat -bona
```

This will give you a list of all your active connections. Use that list to match up with svchost viewer and you can eliminate items by due process.

This is the best method I have found to validate the legitimacy of all those svchost.exe items in Task Manager

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

This can cause by some crack or USB dongle that run constantly to make sure the software you use is legally licensed, or some type of virus that run as service to consume the CPU resources.